# Bootstrap 2.3 center div content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

On this website avoirundevis.fr i need to center content like this on this picture : http://www.evernote.com/l/AMM-nvY7omBHtLzs4VFLBhTzw6wkkTS5rjw/

I have trying with this code http://jsfiddle.net/94150148/utxnmr1h/ but i don't know how do this, thanks for help

```
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6"><a href="/devis/fenetres-pvc-bois-alu/">Fenêtres (PVC, bois, alu)</a></div>
<div class="span6"><a href="/devis/facade-ravalement-enduit/">Façade (ravalement, enduit,...)</a></div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class="span6"><a href="/devis/construction-extension/">Construction - Extension</a></div>
<div class="span6"><a href="/devis/sols-interieurs/">Sols intérieurs</a></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styles baby:

I updated the html/css on your jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/utxnmr1h/7/

css:

```
.container {
text-aling:center;
width:100%;
}
.row-fluid {
width:80%;
margin:auto;
}
```

html: I added a div outside the ones you provided and named it container.

Comment: I don't think this is what he needs, as he wants to center the containers and not the content.

Comment: @Laurent Cool, if it answers your questions, please accept the answer.